# Расширение списка при изменении элементов по индексу

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Задание написать программу расчета сетевого трафика. Проблема заключается в том, что при попытке заменить элемент списка по индексу методом `list.insert()`, список расширяется, хотя должен заменять числа списка по их индексу в цикле:

```
list_matrix = []
for line in open("mtrx2.txt", "r").read().split("\n"):
    for unit in line.split("]", 3):
        list_matrix.append(list(map(lambda x: int(x), unit.split(","))))

i_z = len(list_matrix)+1
i_b = len(list_matrix)+1

list_table = \
            ['Шифр\nнаименования',
             'Продолжи\nтельность\nработ',
             'Ранние\nНР',
             'Ранние\nОР',
             'Поздние\nНР',
             'Поздние\nОР',
             'Резервы\nобщие',
             'Резервы\nчастные']

#Ввод основных и дополнительных переменных
m_i = []
m_j = []
m_Tij = []
m_TijRN = []
m_TijRO = []
m_Tij_MAX = []
m_TijPO = []
m_TijPN = []
m_Rij = []
m_rij = []
m_rijS=[]
iM=[]
#Шифр и продолжительность
for i in range(len(list_matrix)):
    iM.append(i)
    for j in range(len(list_matrix)):
        if list_matrix[i][j] >= 0:
            m_i.append(i)
            m_j.append(j)
            m_Tij.append(list_matrix[i][j])

#Ранниие
for i in range(len(m_i)):
    if m_i[i] == 0:
        m_TijRN.insert(i, 0)
    for j in range(len(m_j)):
        if m_i[i] == m_j[j]:
            m_TijRN.insert(i, (m_Tij[j] + m_TijRN[j]))
    m_TijRO.insert(i, (m_Tij[i] + m_TijRN[i]))

for i in range(13):
    m_TijPO.append(0)
    m_TijPN.append(0)
    m_Rij.append(0)
    m_rij.append(0)

m_Tij.reverse()
m_j.reverse()
m_i.reverse()
print('\n',m_Tij,'\n',m_i,'\n',m_j)
print(len(m_TijPO))
print(len(m_TijPN))
#Поздние
for i in range(13):
    if m_j[i] == 7:
        m_TijPO.insert(i, 19)
        m_TijPN.insert(i, (m_TijPO[i] - m_Tij[i]))

print('\n', m_TijPN, '\n', m_TijPO)
print(len(m_TijPO))
print(len(m_TijPN))
for i in range(13):
    for j in range(13):
        if m_i[i] == m_j[j]:
            m_TijPO.insert(j, m_TijPN[j])
            m_TijPN.insert(i, (m_TijPO[i] - m_Tij[i]))


print('\n', m_TijPN, '\n', m_TijPO)
print(len(m_TijPO))
print(len(m_TijPN))

#Частные резервы
for j in range(len(m_j)):
    for i in range(len(m_i)):
        if m_j[j] == m_i[i]:
            m_rijS.insert(j, (m_TijRN[i]))
    if m_j[j] == max(m_j):
        m_rij.insert(j, (m_Rij[j]))
    else:
        m_rij.insert(j, (m_rijS[j] - m_TijRN[j] - m_Tij[j]))

for i in range(len(m_i)):
    print(i+1, 'точка',
          m_i[i], '–', m_j[i],
          m_Tij[i],
          m_TijRN[i],
          m_TijRO[i],
          m_TijPN[i],
          m_TijPO[i],
          m_Rij[i],
          m_rij[i])
```

Интересует сам этот фрагмент:

```
    for i in range(13):
        if m_j[i] == 7:
            m_TijPO.insert(i, 19)
            m_TijPN.insert(i, (m_TijPO[i] - m_Tij[i]))
    for i in range(13):
        for j in range(13):
            if m_i[i] == m_j[j]:
                m_TijPO.insert(j, m_TijPN[j])
                m_TijPN.insert(i, (m_TijPO[i] - m_Tij[i]))
```

По заданию нужно для начала найти максимальное начало работ по j-ому шифру наименования, затем присвоить это значение `Поздним окончаниям работ` по всем тем же j-ым элементам, в данном случае их 3 (j-ое равно 7, сами работы = 19), затем находить позднее начало работ по тем же j-ым(=7) таким образом, что из поздних окончаний работ отнять продолжительность T(ij) по j-ому(всё еще =7). После чего идет цикл, Позднее начало работ(i=j, например если посмотреть с конца 6 (элемент списка с индексом 12) и j-ый элемент, равный 6 (с индексом 10, другого массива)), должен равняться позднему окончанию по j-му(17). И так продолжается до того момента, пока не прибудем в начало.

Пробовал начинать индекс с начала разными методами `list.[::-1]` `reverse` и другими. Буду очень признателен если хотя бы объясните почему при попытке изменить число по индексу в уже существующем списке (заполненный нулями) метод `list.insert()` расширяет его при выполненных (if) условиях (что я и так понял).

Вот итог выполненного задания. Проверяю себя на этой таблице. В конечном итоге программа должна работать с любым количеством данных (по шифру и продолжительности работ 1 и 2 колонка).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

myList.insert(1, 111)   #  вставить
print(myList)
[1, 111, 2, 3, 4, 5]

myList[1] = 222         #  заменить
 print(myList)
[1, 222, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: спасибо за информацию, всё поменял, но решение всё равно в итоге такое же, но уже без расширения списка. буду искать проблему, еще раз спасибо. понял свою ошибку